# Why doesn't Frida find a class?

Tags: java, okhttp, frida

I need to execute trace for the ancw.intercept method. But I can not find the class "ancw", only its parent class "agzn".

```java
public final class ancw extends agzn implements Interceptor {

    ...

    public final OkHttpResponse intercept(Chain aVar) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}


public abstract class agzn {
    ...
}
```

Frida-script:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    Java.performNow(function() {
        console.log('searching...')
        var pattern = 'ancw'
        Java.enumerateLoadedClasses({
            onMatch: function(aClass) {
                if (aClass.match(pattern)) {
                    console.log(aClass)
                }
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                console.log('end')
            }
        });
    });   
}, 5000);
```

What can cause such an effect?

**Update**

Here is the smali part of the file with the code before the constructor. I had to add additional text so that stackoverflow allowed this edit.

```
.class public final Lancw;
.super Lagzn;

.implements Lbatx;

.field private final a:Lbaiz;
.field private final b:Lbaiz;

.method public constructor <init>(Lazcn;Lbait;)V
 .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
     value = {
            "(",
            "Lazcn<",
            "Lrqr;",
            ">;",
            "Lbait<",
            "Landj;",
            ">;)V"
     }
 .end annotation

...
```

Comment: The code looks decompiled. Are you sure the class names are correct and not modified by the decompiler?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure these are the correct names. I can find these classes as smali files.

Comment: Can you show smali for ancw? Until ancw constructor at least

Answer (score 1):

late reply but hope this helps someone in the future

first of all make sure you're code is inside a `Java.perform` and you used the -U when launching frida

if yes then there is 2 possibilities either the class is not being called as java only loads classes until they are used (this can include app actions or specific screens) or the classloader used to load the class is different than what java normally uses [have a look here](https://serializethoughts.com/2021/05/07/frida-java-classloaders)

a [example](https://github.com/defnotcat/shape-unpacker/blob/master/agent/index.js) of this is shape security sdk where they load classes with a special class loader